# Confused by Argument passing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a function which requires three arguments to be passed. The first argument is a fixed value, second argument is a range which is later on used by the for loop in code. The third argument is a range/list of values. What I want is that for every value in second argument range shall take a single corresponding value from third argument.
for example, I want that when second argument value is 10, the third argument should be 1.
             When second argument value is 19, the third argument should be 2.
             Similarly, When second argument value is 28, the third argument should be 3.
             and so on....
In other words, I can put it like this:
Each time "for" loops run for each value of "n", there shall be a unique and constantly increasing value of "f".
Thank you in advance.

```
def runFunct(funct):
    itrange = funct[0]
    nrange = funct[1]
    frange = funct[2]


    for f in frange:
        for n in nrange:
            print(f*n)
            ....
funct1 = [1, range(10,101,9), ?????]     
runFunct(funct3)
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want a function that takes two arguments.  The third value can be worked out in the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your function only runs if your 2nd and 3rd arguments are related in a certain way.

So there are 2 possibilities :

1. Keep your 3 argument-function and add a check phase at the begining of the function, like :

```py
def myFunction(i, nrange, frange):
    # Check property
    for n in nrange:
        if not <your relation between n and f>:
            raise ValueError("The relation between nrange and frange is not good")

    # Do what your function must do
```

2. Like Alex said in the comments : if your 3rd argument can be computed with the 2nd argument, just give 2 arguments to your function and compute the third, like :

```py
def myFunction(i, nrange):
    # Compute frange
    frange = <Way to compute frange from nrange>

    # Do what your function must do
```